# Angularjs Use Promises in Service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a page that makes several calls to the api to return records for one page.  It is a lot of information and takes time to load.  I am trying to chain promises to give the data time to load before the page that displays it loads.  I use the following to call the first part:

```
$scope.selectAll = function () {
    alert('Please wait while your data is loaded...');
    $scope.print.sections = angular.copy($scope.sections);
    var promise = getAllSections($scope.print.sections);

    promise.then(function () {
        $scope.dataLoading = false;
        alert('Dataload complete!');
    })

};

function getAllSections(sections) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    deferred.notify('Getting Data');
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.print.sections.length; i++) {
        getSectionData($scope.print.sections[i]);
    }
    deferred.resolve('Data Complete')
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

My problem is the function "getSectionData" calls several functions in my service below (this only part of the service for brevity):

```
angular.module('myModule').service('contractorService', [
     '$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {

         this.getcompletioncertificatepage = function () {
             return $http.post('/SSQV4/SSQV5/Contractor/GetCompletionCertificate')
         };
         this.getselectedcontractorservices = function (id) {
             return $http.post('/SSQV4/SSQV5/Contractor/GetSelectedContractorServices?sectionId=' + id)
         }
         this.getavailablecontractorservices = function (id) {
             return $http.post('/SSQV4/SSQV5/Contractor/GetAvailableContractorServices?sectionId=' + id)
         };

         this.getgeneraluploadimage = function (id) {
             return $http.post('/SSQV4/SSQV5/Contractor/GetGeneralUploadDocument?imageType=' + id)
         };
         this.getemrtabulation = function () {
             return $http.post('/SSQV4/SSQV5/Contractor/GetEMRTabulationColumns')
         };

         this.getimage = function (id, docDate) {
             return $http.post('/SSQV4/SSQV5/Contractor/GetImage', {"emrDetailID": id, "docDate" : docDate})
          };
         this.getemrquestion = function () {
             return $http.post('/SSQV4/SSQV5/Contractor/GetEMRQuestion')
         };
```

In my controller, I call these like so:

```
       function getSectionData(section) {
            var id = section.QuestionSectionID;
                    contractorService.getIncidentColumns(clusterId)
                    .success(function (data) {
    ...}
                contractorService.getgeneralincidentquestions(id)
                .success(function (data) {
...}

    ... (there are many calls to the service here)
        }
```

I'm trying to figure out how to use promises with the Service for each of the functions that I have to call and chain them so that the "then" function in my "selectAll" function doesn't display until ALL of the get functions have been completed.  I tried putting this in the servcie:

```
       this.getIncidentDetailByQtr = function (id) {
     var deferred = $q.defer();
     $http.post('/SSQV4/SSQV5/Contractor/GetIncidentDetailByQtr?tabId=' + id)
     return deferred.promise;
 };
```

and this in the controller:

```
            var promise = contractorService.getIncidentDetailByQtr(7)
            .then(function (data) {
                $scope.qtrDetail = data;
                deleteTableRows($scope.qtrDetail);
            });
```

which works, until I try to add more promises (i.e. var promiseA, etc.) to the other calls.

When I try to do this:

```
                var promise = contractorService.getIncidentDetailByQtr(7)
                .then(function (data) {
                    $scope.qtrDetail = data;
                    deleteTableRows($scope.qtrDetail);
                });
                $scope.incidentTableDefinition = '<table>' + firstRow + secondRow + thirdRow + '<tr style="text-align:center" ng-repeat="q in qtrDetail">' + repeatRow + '</tr></table>';
                firstRow = '';
                secondRow = '';
                thirdRow = '';
                repeatRow = '';
                var promiseA = contractorService.getincidentsummarycolumns(9)
                .then(function (data) {
                    $scope.summaryColumns = data;
```

I receive the error "Unable to get property 'then' of undefined or null reference".

The function "getSelectedData" makes about 15 calls to the service.  I need the initial "resolve" to not execute until AFTER all of them have completed.  I am new to this, but I'm pretty sure that this has to do with chaining promises, but I can't figure out how to accomplish what I need here.  ANY assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: There is `$q.all()` for this job ([ref](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)).

Comment: Thanks for that.  By searching for $q.all() I was able to find the answer for this.

Comment: It would be nice if you posted the answer (and accept your own answer) so that future readers can benefit from this!

Answer (score 0):

Got the following to work after a little research on "$q.all":

```
 $scope.selectAll = function () {
        alert('Please wait while your data is loaded...');
        $scope.print.sections = angular.copy($scope.sections);
        var promise = getAllSections($scope.print.sections);

        promise.then(function () {
            $scope.dataLoading = false;
            alert('Dataload complete!');
        })

    };
    function getAllSections(sections) {
        var promises = [];
        angular.forEach(sections, function (section) {
            var promise = getSectionData(section)
            promises.push(promise);
        });
        return $q.all(promises);
    }
```

Hope this helps someone else.  Happy coding!